# No Internet after awhile for the Wi-Fi connected devices of the router which uses as Access Point (Extender)

Tags: wireless-access-point, adsl-router

My goal is to access internet via Wi-Fi network created by my old ADSL router (Huawei EchoLife HG556a) which has connected to my main router (ZTE F660) via Ethernet cable. It is working without a problem when the secondary router (HG556a) has only one device connected via Wi-Fi.

If secondary router has more than one connected, all those devices connected to the secondary router via Wi-Fi will have no internet access after awhile.

The devices connected via LAN port of the secondary router will have internet access but not able to log into the secondary router configuration (ping failed to the secondary router address: 192.168.1.100).
Here is the [screenshot of the message display by the browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tCNtU.png) when try to load a web page. The Windows Network Diagnostics also suggested to restart the router. But no problem for the devices which has connected to the Primary router (F660) via of its Wi-Fi network.

Once I restart the secondary router, I will have the internet access again only for awhile. The time to lose the internet is varying.

I tried with various type of settings (The secondary router doesn't have a mode like 'AP/Router/Repeater' to set) but no luck. Here are my configurations.

Primary Router (HG556a)
IP:192.168.1.1
DHCP: Enabled (Range 192.168.1.2 to 192.168.1.99)

Secondary Router (F660)
IP:192.168.1.100
DHCP: Off
DNS: 192.168.1.1 (I also tried 8.8.8.8 but no luck)
[Screenshot of the page to set DNS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I3WNs.png)

ROUTING: Enabled automatic assigned default gateway [Screenshot of the page to set ROUTING](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XmrZ0.png)

As of the above configuration did not work, I tried to set WAN interface and used that interface in the ROUTING as follow. This may not relevant but just tried.

1. Select to add ADSL uplink
2. [Set PVC configurations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zV7A2.png)
3. [Set connection type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vwyZ9.png)
4. [Set WAN IP settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GnRJB.png)
5. [Set NAT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ttIWt.png)
6. [Set ROUTING default gateway to that interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tB8pf.png)

But nothing has changed. It gives the same result and Internet lost for the Wi-Fi devices of secondary router.

What kind of additional settings are required to achieve the goal?